# Как лучше организовать архитектуру кода для работы с Room и Курсорами Android?

Tags: android, room

В задании нужно реализовать работу с БД через Room и Курсоры. Реализации должны переключаться в runtime. Я реализовал CRUD операции через Room. Осталось придумать как переключать реализацию на курсоры. Есть следующие мысли: сделать две имплементации Dao для Room и Курсоров и в Репозитории используя делегат возвращать реализации для Room либо Курсоров читая preference.
2й вопрос: У меня есть dao  интерфейс с аннотациями для Room , могу ли я этот интерфейс использовать для курсора?

Comment: я бы седелал две сущности, для Room и курсора. Спрятал бы их за фасадом, а к фасаду обращался, а он уже бы сам решал, что и куда отправлять, чтобы скрыть реализацию от окружения. 2) дао для рума же генерится с анотаций, курсор же работает иначе.

Answer (score 0):

В общем сделал в Repository поле CarDao так:

```html
private var carDao:CarDao=database.carDao()
      get(){
            val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            val dataSource = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("switch",true)
             return if(dataSource) database.carDao() else
                 CarDatabaseCursor(context)
        }
```